# Storing when something is in use

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to track license usage for software and the software does not have any sort of metric that we can use. The need for this comes when it is time to pay the maintenance quarterly and trying to split the cost to each department's budget based on how many users each department has.  We want to be able to see usage over the last week/month/year to get something that is automatic and a little less "I think, maybe...".

I want to store the data so that we can use it but I am not sure the based way to structure this

What I am currently working with is a command that I can run to get a list, and it has the who and the what and when they pulled the license.

I have two options that I can see (I am open to other suggestions as well):

1. Query every 5 minutes, and capture who,what software, and current timestamp and then put that all in a single record.  This will lead to a large amount of records being generated.
2. Query every 5 minutes and for each user/software combination check the db for an existing record that has a start and no stop and add a record if it does not exist and update a stamp if it does. Anything that does not get updated we close it with the current stamp. Basically a in/out system.

Again the goal is to see who was using what software and break that up by department to figure out the total usage for billing.

- The user pool for this software is about 50 (max) and average about 30 concurrent.
- Some some of the software just adds to the base software (like added features) so a single user can pull many licenses if the need is there.
- For reporting we wont use it but it would be nice to see who is hogging the seats that we have a smaller number of.

Comment: Check out various auditing plugins.

Comment: Many years ago, the billing where I worked was "$600 per cpu-hour".  I laugh at that now -- I could buy a decent machine, complete with MySQL, for one hour's worth.  There comes a point when the cost to bill for something is more than the loss of simply giving it free or flat rate.  When did you last pay individually for each "long distance call"?